# OpenGL Rotate something that has been popped off matrix

Tags: opengl

I have a question about applying transformations to textures/vertices (I'm an OpenGL learner). I've got a situation where I'm using SharpGL's DrawText function. You can specify the X and Y coordinate but I want to rotate the text so that it's oriented vertically. The function doesn't take an angle though. The way that SharpGL writes text is that it gets an array of bitmaps that it writes to the screen.

No matter what I try, my text always comes out horizontal.

The gl.DrawText function does the following (I dug into the source code).

gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.PushMatrix();
            gl.LoadIdentity();

```
        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        gl.GetInteger(OpenGL.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
        gl.Ortho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);

        //  Create the appropriate modelview matrix.
        gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.PushMatrix();
        gl.LoadIdentity();
        gl.Color(r, g, b);
        gl.RasterPos(x, y);

        gl.PushAttrib(OpenGL.GL_LIST_BIT | OpenGL.GL_CURRENT_BIT |
            OpenGL.GL_ENABLE_BIT | OpenGL.GL_TRANSFORM_BIT);
        gl.Color(r, g, b);
        gl.Disable(OpenGL.GL_LIGHTING);
        gl.Disable(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.Disable(OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.RasterPos(x, y);

        //  Set the list base.
        gl.ListBase(fontBitmapEntry.ListBase);

        //  Create an array of lists for the glyphs.
        var lists = text.Select(c => (byte) c).ToArray();

        //  Call the lists for the string.
        gl.CallLists(lists.Length, lists);
        gl.Flush();
```

Is there a way that I can make transformation calls apply to any drawing that has already been made and had the associated matrices popped off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If SharpGL is using `glBitmap()` behind the scenes you'll have to render the text to a texture (`glReadPixels()`/PBO/FBO) then render a (rotated) quad with that texture.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Windows wglUseFontBitmaps function? It's a Windows graphics library extension. It appears that SharpGL is calling this to create bitmaps in a display list which is then triggered via a call to CallLists. According to MSDN, it is calling glBitmap behind the scenes. So I would do a glReadPixels and rotate that? What happens if it's overlapping with something? If I constructed an elegant scene could it read in stuff that I don't want?

Comment: If you go the `glReadPixels()` route you'll generally want to render your strings after your initial `glClear()` when your framebuffer is empty, then issue another `glClear()` before drawing your scene.  That way you won't inadvertently pick up any scene colors.